# Border radius to curve inwards?

Tags: css, border

How can I have the border to curve inwards instead of outwards?

For instance - this is curving outwards:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff9d2f, #ff6126);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font: 44px "Arial";
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <h1>Section Content</h1>
</section>
```

I would like it to curve inwards, is it possible?

Comment: @LokeshGupta any example please?

Comment: Check i posted working example as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like below example

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff9d2f, #ff6126);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font: 44px "Arial";
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
}

header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <h1>Section Content</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate it using another box, if this is what you need.

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff9d2f, #ff6126);
}

header:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 40%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 40%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font: 44px "Arial";
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <h1>Section Content</h1>
</section>
```